# ContentPlaceHolderID added to all my field id's. how to control them?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have aspx pages which uses repetitive code. So I put them on a masterfile and referring that in all other files. I have used the `<asp:Content ID>` in all other pages where I included master page like,

```
<asp:Content ID="Step1Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
```

My issue is now all the field id's has a suffix of `ContentPlaceHolderID_fieldName` and because of this my javascript doesn't work.

```
<input id='chkRaces_1' type='checkbox' runat='server' onclick="enableShow50();" /><label for='chkRaces_1'>American Indian or Alaska Native</label><br />
```

When I debug, it appears like,

```
<input id="MainContent_chkRaces_1" type="checkbox" onclick="enableShow50(<%# Eval(chkRaces_1.ClientID) %>);" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkRaces_1">
```

and my Javascript which refrences using `id='chkRaces_1'` fails. I thought of replacing all the inputs with `<asp:ListItem>` tags n so, but I get error."type HtmlInputCheckBox" is not compatible with "ListItem". So I got to change the class too which I don't want to.

What else I can do to achieve the same with minimal change in aspx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410598.aspx), but keep in mind that's only available in .NET 4.0 and above.

```
<asp:Label ID="SelectedSport" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:Label>
```

Or in JavaScript:

```
var userLabel = document.getElementById('<%=SelectedSport.ClientID%>');
```

if you are trying to access the control in javascript, then using .ClientID is probably your best bet, as it doesn't require change in aspx page

Answer (score 2):

To not append the Container's ID to the control's id, set the ClientIDMode="Static" property of the control.

```
<input id='chkRaces_1' type='checkbox' ClientIDMode="Static" runat='server' onclick="enableShow50();" /><
```