# Collapsable list, doesnt respond to click

Tags: html, css, asp.net, radio-button

I am making a website, trying to get the following code to work.
Fun part is, here in the code snipp thing of Stackoverflow it works. but on my website it doesn't.  Does anyone have any idea?  Its exactly the same code  webpage: 
When clicking on the blue bar its supposed to collapse and or show another item.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
div.emailblok {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
nav.emails {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
nav.emails > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav.emails > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
nav.emails > ul > li > label,
nav.emails > ul > li > a {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 118);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(30, 144, 255), rgb(0, 0, 118));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(30, 144, 255), rgb(0, 0, 118));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(30, 144, 255), rgb(0, 0, 118));
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(30, 144, 255), rgb(0, 0, 118));
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  font-size: .7rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: .4rem;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav.emails > ul > li > label + input {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
nav.emails > ul > li > label:hover,
nav.emails > ul > li > a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(1, 4, 122);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(1, 4, 122), rgb(1, 4, 122));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(1, 4, 122), rgb(1, 4, 122));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(1, 4, 122), rgb(1, 4, 122));
  background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(1, 4, 122), rgb(1, 4, 122));
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav.emails > ul > li > label + input:checked + div {
  max-height: 500px;
}
nav.emails > ul > li > div {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="emailblok">
  <nav class="emails">
    <ul>
      <li runat="server">
        <label for="Nummer0">Nummer 0</label>
        <input type="radio" runat="server" name="Email" id="Nummer0" checked />
        <div>
          Helemmoooie email
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li runat="server">
        <label for="Nummer1">Nummer 1</label>
        <input type="radio" runat="server" name="Email" id="Nummer1" />
        <div>
          Helemmoooie email
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>

      </li>
      <li runat="server">
        <label for="Nummer2">nummer 2</label>
        <input type="radio" runat="server" name="Email" id="Nummer2" />
        <div>
          Helemmoooie email
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the *console* as there are several *404 (Not Found)* errors on the give URL!

Comment: Those were old references, removed them. the menu on the left side has the same way of collapsing (you dont see al the items once logged in it has more items) but that does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the `for` attribute of your `label` tag to the `id` of your `radio` button for each of the `li` and you will good to go.

> Just as you did in your Question, i.e. why its working here in *Stack Snippet*.

As:

```
<li>
    <label for="MainContent_Nummer2">nummer 2</label>
    <input value="Nummer2" name="ctl00$MainContent$Email" type="radio" id="MainContent_Nummer2">
     <div>Helemmoooie email<br><br><br></div>
</li>
```

Comment: That brings me to another question then, In my source code the code is exactly as it is in my question. but when i inspect the source on the website it has changed the id to "MainContent_Nummer2"   Any idea?

Comment: It seemed to me that, on your page, wherever you've used `name="ctl00$MainContent...` on any tag then its `id` attribute as string **MainContent_**

Comment: Well, the name is supposed to be "email"  but that also gets disformed. I dont really know why

Comment: Check this [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10503567/4763084), this may help.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the console. The code you have shared works fine but the location of the css or resource is incorrect in the application.

Check the console it shows :
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Those were old references, removed them.  the menu on the left side has the same way of collapsing (you dont see al the items once logged in it has more items) but that does work.